# Enable/ Disable different sets of Controllers in based on mode specified at startup Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, model-view-controller, web

While starting my Spring MVC war I need to specify the mode.
Based on mode it should start different set of controllers.
Is it possible to do the same by specifying mode/ applicable controllers
while starting it?

A similar question [Spring MVC web application - enabling / disabling controller from property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079899/spring-mvc-web-application-enabling-disabling-controller-from-property) only talks of test but I need to have various combinations and start all controllers as default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring in general has a [profile](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-definition-profiles) mechanism that lets you register different beans in different environments

When you bootstrap it according to doc, distinguishing controllers is as simple as annotating them on a class level with e.g. `@Profile("mode1")` vs `@Profile("mode2")`